# Julia as a working language for non-CS domain experts?

Tags: julia

I build structural design optimization software together with civil engineers in a large renewable energy company. The way we have set it up, the domain experts will do most of their own code (think structural validation of steel part, geophysical response models,...), and my team is responsible for integrating it all and building optimization algorithms on top.

Currently everything is matlab because this is what the engineers are taught at school. We are starting to consider rebuilding the system from scratch, and one question that pops up is what language to use.

My prioritized checklist is:

- Easy to learn for a non-CS minded civil engineer
- Well suited for linear algebra calculation, large algebraic expressions and numerical work in general
- Existing numerical libraries with root finding, basic optimizers, etc. -- or solid support for C/Fortran integration.

So far my favorite is Python, which I have seen several of the engineers get up to speed with in a few weeks, but I was wondering if Julia would also fit the bill.

Do you have experience using Julia as a domain expert language, and would you recommend it for this purpose?

(Keeping this specific to Julia to make it an answerable question -- but feel free to chime in with other language options!)

Comment: This question is interesting, but probably not well suited to stackoverflow, as it is a question about personal opinions. You can ask it on reddit or maybe discourse.julialang.org. (Personally, as a non-CS, domain expert, I find Julia great for each point on your checklist.)

Comment: @DNF Thank you for the reddit suggestion. I knew it was borderline, but was sort of hoping that the call for actual experiences would make it ok.

Answer (score 5):

Like mentioned in the comments this is a question for julia discourse.

However, I cannot resist to comment on your list.

1. Easy to learn for a non-CS minded civil engineer

Julia is slightly more difficult then Python. I have been teaching Julia to several groups of people and basically if your team has a background such as Python or Matlab transformation to Julia is painless and natural.

2. Well suited for linear algebra calculation, large algebraic expressions and numerical work in general

This is exactly what is this language designed for. Julia totally overcomes each of Python's shortcomings in that areas.

3. Existing numerical libraries with root finding, basic optimizers, etc. -- or solid support for C/Fortran integration.

Have a look at https://github.com/JuliaMath and https://github.com/JuliaOpt/
Additionally if you are interested in linear and nonlinear programming have a look at JuMP at https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl - this is ingenious and beautiful package

Additionally, C and Fortran work out-of-the-box: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/
Finally, it is worth noting that you can also load and directly use Python libraries in Julia via the `PyCall.jl` package.